# Reading json with key:value in ext.store in sencha touch 2

Tags: ajax, json, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to load a particular json file into a listview; but sencha proxy doesn't seem to understand the key pairs of "CurrencyName" and "Value". I'm clueless on how to associate those two values into usable data.

Here's the json:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1335294053,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 3.6732,
        "AFN": 48.32,
        "ALL": 106.040001
    }
}
```

my store:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost/CurrencyFX/latest.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'rates'
    }
},
```

my model:

```
Ext.define('CurrencyFX.model.Currency', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [ 'name', 'value' ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to write your own JSON reader subclass to make this work, as the data you are dealing with isn't an array.

Thankfully, doing this is fairly simple. Here is something that should do the job:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.reader.Custom', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    alias : 'reader.custom',

    getRoot: function(data) {
        if (this.rootAccessor) {
            data = this.rootAccessor.call(this, data);
        }

        var values = [],
            name;

        for (name in data) {
            values.push({
                name: name,
                value: data[name]
            });
        }

        return values;
    }
});
```

Which will work with the following store configuration:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'value'],
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '0000.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'custom',
            rootProperty: 'rates'
        }
    }
});
```

Notice the reader `type` is now **custom**.

I tested this locally with your data and it seemed to work just fine.